# redirect and print script output using for loop and awk in linux

Tags: linux, for-loop, awk

I have a script which give out put like this :

> my_script <*variables*>

output like this :

```
    text1   text3     textext3   texxt6   textxx2
    textx3  textext3  textext1   text4    text4
    text1x  textx2    text5      textxt0  textxx
    ..........
    ..........
    .......... so on
```

now I want to redirect the output and print like this

> print "**some_text** *col_3@col_4* **some_more_text** *col_4*"

ans will be like this:

**some_text** *textext3@texxt6* **some_more_text** *texxt6*

**some_text** *textext1@text4* **some_more_text** *text4*

**some_text** *text5@textxt0* **some_more_text** *textxt0*

..... so on

## col_3 = all values in column 3, col_4 = all values in column 4

what is the simple way to print like this using for loop and awk
NOTE : There is no correlation between all fields and length is not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWK solution:

```
awk '{ print "some_text" OFS $3 "@" $4 OFS "some_more_text" OFS $4 }' YOURFILE
```

Or in your case:

```
your_script <variables> | awk '{ print "some_text" OFS $3 "@" $4 OFS "some_more_text" OFS $4 }'
```

Example input:

```
    text1   text3     textext3   texxt6   textxx2
    textx3  textext3  textext1   text4    text4
    text1x  textx2    text5      textxt0  textxx
```

Example output:

```
some_text textext3@texxt6 some_more_text texxt6
some_text textext1@text4 some_more_text text4
some_text text5@textxt0 some_more_text textxt0
```

Comment: Hi @Andriy,

Thanks for you answer it worked with some little problem
I want output like this 

some_text textext3@texxt6 some_more_text.*texxt6
some_text textext1@text4 some_more_text.text4
some_text text5@textxt0 some_more_text.textxt0

not like this

some_text textext3@texxt6 some_more_text.<space>texxt6
some_text textext1@text4 some_more_text.<space>text4
some_text text5@textxt0 some_more_text.<space>textxt0

I dont want the space

Comment: What separator are you using? If tab, you need to add `BEGIN { OFS="\t" }` to the start of awk script. But if you want multiple spaces of variable length, I can't help you.